# React how to call the element inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Tables from "../src/components/Tables";

const uuidv4 = () =>
  ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (
      c ^
      (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & (15 >> (c / 4)))
    ).toString(16)
  );

const CreateTimeTable = (title, rows) => {
  title.map(_title => ({
    title: _title,
    id: uuidv4(),
    data: Array.from({ length: rows }).map(_rows => ({
      id: uuidv4(),
      container: " "
    }))
  }));
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    days: CreateTimeTable([
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday",
      "Sunday"
    ])
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.state.days.title[1]}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How do I call the element from the function "CreateTimeTable" inside the div element.

Just started out react hope I can get some help ! 
Thank you!

I keep getting error such ascproperty undefined

Comment: you are not returning anything from `CreateTimeTable` method, put a return here: `return title.map(_title => ({` also it should be `{this.state.days[0].title}` because days will be an array.

Comment: @MayankShukla if I pass a prop do I pass it as 

<Tables tables={this.state.days} />

Because I can see that I wouldnt be able to do days[0] or days[1] from my child components

Comment: yes you can pass like this: `<Tables tables={this.state.days} />` but now it will `tables[0]` or `[1]` because of key tables.